# Space between two SPAN/DIV recommendation

Tags: html, css, whitespace, removing-whitespace

I am having the following HTML in which I am displaying an icon in front of a line of text (to have something like a grid/table like view):

```
<div class="icon">FOO</div> <div class="text">this is an example</div>
```

The CSS would look like this (therefore the same question applies to SPAN):

```
.icon, .text {
   display: inline-block;
}
```

I'd like to know if it is best practice to have a space between those two DIVs (like in my example) or of the DIVs should be connected (spacing is a question of layout and should be handled by CSS only)?

If I am connecting two DIVs and/or SPANs and a user double-clicks an element (e.g. `.text` in this example), the first word of the prior DIV (`.icon` in this example) would be selected too. This is why I assume a hard space in HTML would be recommended.

Comment: What do you mean by 'space between' ?

Comment: It all depends why do you want `space between`. You could use `margin` for that, and then you can control exactly how big the margin should be. `div` and `span` are two different elements that behave differently. One is `block` one is `inline`. Please be more specific in your question otherwise this can be considered opinion based or too broad or even unclear

Comment: it's simple : don't leave your HTML code decide for you, space or not space you should keep the control, what if you keep the space and your code get minified later?

Comment: Don'r muddle HTML and CSS. The spacing is part of the semantic content. `<div>hello</div> <div>world</div>` is two [paragraphs](https://w3c.github.io/html/dom.html#paragraph), `<span>hello</span> <span>world</span>` is one paragraph. They are not the same. Space characters are significant in runs of phrasing content.